# Creating a user defined PDF

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a derived distribution which I want to play with, which is of the form
$$\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}2^{-2+\frac{x}{10}} 5^{-1+\frac{x}{10}} e^{-\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}} 2^{-1+\frac{x}{10}} 5^{\frac{x}{10}}}\ln(10)$$
This is a $x \rightarrow 10^{x/20}$ transformation of the Rayleigh distribution, derrived by:
$$R(x, \sigma) = \frac{x}{\sigma^{2}} e^{-x^{2}/(2\sigma)^{2}}$$
and consider $X = 20 \log_{10}(x)$, so $x = 10^{X/20}$. Then
$$R_X(X, \sigma) = \frac{10^{X/20}}{\sigma^{2}} e^{-(10^{X/20})^{2}/(2\sigma)^{2}} \frac{d}{dX}10^{X/20}$$ Plugging into mathematica 
`10^(x/20)/\[Sigma]^2 Exp[-(10^(x/20))^2/ (2 \[Sigma]^2)]D[10^(x/20),x]`  gives the top expression.

The function appears well behaved for values I am interested in, here I choose `\[Sigma] = 0.00005` which when plotted gives

```
Plot[(2^(-2 + x/10) 5^(-1 + x/10)E^(-((2^(-1 + x/10) 5^(x/10))/\[Sigma]^2))Log[10])/\[Sigma]^2, {x, -180, -50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I want to use this function as a PDF so I can do some analysis I have tried

```
CustomDistribution[\[Sigma]_] := ProbabilityDistribution[Evaluate[10^(x/20)/\[Sigma]^2 Exp[-(10^(x/20))^2/ (2 \[Sigma]^2)]D[10^(x/20),x]],{x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Which returns

```
Function[\[FormalX], (
 2^(-2 + \[FormalX]/10) 5^(-1 + \[FormalX]/10)
   E^(-((2^(-1 + \[FormalX]/10) 5^(\[FormalX]/10))/\[Sigma]^2))
   Log[10])/\[Sigma]^2]
```

But if I now try and plot this, with the same value for $\sigma$, as

```
Plot[PDF[CustomDistribution[\[Sigma]]][x],{x, -60, -160}]
```

I just get a flat line. Am I defining my PDF incorrectly? Is it possible to make a user defined PDF

Comment: Did you actually run the plot I submitted? What you say is demonstrably not true.

Comment: `Plot[(2^(-2 + x/10) 5^(-1 + x/10)E^(-((2^(-1 + x/10) 5^(x/10))/\[Sigma]^2))Log[10])/\[Sigma]^2, {x, -180, -50}, PlotRange -> All]` It is defined. Just run it. I will add some text how I derived the expression.

Comment: @wolfies See above. I genuinely don't understand why you say the expression is not valid for $x<0$. You can even demonstrate the transformation validity by simulation. Generate some Rayleigh distributed data transform with $20\log_{10}x$ and then you will see exactly the distribution outlined in the top equation.

Comment: Using $Y$ for the transformed variable (rather than X and x) would avoid notation ambiguities.

Comment: Granted, the notation was ambiguous. But perhaps next time actually check code before making an assertion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

When defining a custom distribution, the constraints on the parameters should be included as [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) and the [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) should evaluate the entire expression rather than just the argument to [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html)

```
CustomDistribution[σ_] := 
 Evaluate@ProbabilityDistribution[
   10^(x/20)/σ^2 Exp[-(10^(x/20))^2/(2 σ^2)] D[10^(x/20), 
     x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> σ > 0]
```

The constraints are then available with [`DistributionParameterAssumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionParameterAssumptions.html).

```
assume = DistributionParameterAssumptions[
  CustomDistribution[σ]]

(* σ > 0 *)
```

Verifying that the total probability for the distribution is valid

```
Assuming[assume,
 Integrate[PDF[CustomDistribution[σ], x],
  {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

(* 1 *)
```

The [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) is

```
μ[σ_] = Mean[CustomDistribution[σ]]

(* -((10 (EulerGamma + Log[1/(2 σ^2)]))/Log[10]) *)

μ[0.00005]

(* -85.5171 *)

With[{σ = 0.00005},
 Plot[PDF[CustomDistribution[σ], x],
  {x, -120, -60},
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** It is more straightforward to let Mathematica do all of the work by using [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html).

```
dist[σ_] = TransformedDistribution[20 Log10[x],
   x \[Distributed] RayleighDistribution[σ]];

PDF[dist[σ], x]

(* (2^(-2 + x/10) 5^(-1 + x/10) E^(-((2^(-1 + x/10) 5^(x/10))/σ^2))
  Log[10])/σ^2 *)
```

The constraint on the parameter is then inherited from [`RayleighDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RayleighDistribution.html)

```
DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist[σ]]

(* σ > 0 *)
```

Comment: Wonderful as always. Thanks Bob.

Comment: You can replace `f[x_]:=Evaluate[...]` with `f[x_]=…`, which seems a  bit more direct in my opinion

Comment: @LukasLang - I agree; however, I was trying to point out that the problem was improper placement of the `Evaluate`